# Autofill HTML form page for Web Development

Tags: php, html, forms, autofill

I am created a dynamic registration page using HTML, PHP, and Javascript.  I am trying to make it so that the form would not be submitted unless it meets the requirements of the form.  Some sample requirements are if a field is filled, verified, in email form, or has minimum length.  I have a quite a bit of required fields now and it's a pain to fill all of them when I want to test the form.  I'm using Eclipse IDE and I'm using the built in web browser and a web server to test the form.  I already have code implemented to verify the input upon some basic requirements.

How can I auto fill my HTML form web page with various fields and various types of entry without having to change the code?  This is only for testing purposes to verify that my form is producing the correct output given a set of inputs.

Comment: add an admin flag in your code so you can skip the validation part...

Comment: did you try googling for this?

[W3C Input attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a macro program to autofill the form.  One such program is AutoHotkey.  I am sure there is a more convenient way to do so.  Of course, if you use autohotkey you should use the autowriter as well which can be found using this Stack Overflow post: https://superuser.com/questions/229720/where-can-i-find-a-macro-recorder-for-autohotkey  Best of luck!

Comment: This works for Windows but I just switched over to a Linux work environment.  What would be the equivalent program on Linux that implements this type of functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `value`.  Like this:

```
<input type="text" name="something" value="value here">
```

In case of a `textarea`:

```
<textarea cols="5" rows="5">value here</textarea>
```